# In Linear Algebra, what is the purpose of converting a linear system into an augmented matrix to make it into triangular form?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that you can make a linear system into a triangular form without having to convert the system into an M x N augmented matrix. However, I am very curious as to why one would want to convert a linear system into an augmented matrix in order to put it into a triangular form and then use back substitution in order to solve the system.

Might it have to do with applying the 3 elementary row operations? Thanks people

Comment: It is just a convenient way to keep track of applying row operations on both sides of the equation $Ax=b$ at the same time, while working on pencil and paper. This is one of those things that is emphasized a lot in certain lower level classes, but ultimately is not very deep or important later on. What is important is to understand is the idea of the LU decomposition - that row operations correspond to left multiplications with lower triangular matrices, and so by doing Gaussian elimination you are converting the matrix to a lower triangular matrix times an upper triangular one.